# Most elegant way to convert a byte to an int in Java

Tags: java

Example code:

```
int a = 255;
byte b = (byte) a;
int c = b & 0xff; // Here be dragons
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

So we start with an integer value of 255, convert it to a byte (becoming -1) and then converting it back to an int by using a magic formula. The expected output is:

```
255
-1
255
```

I'm wondering if this `a & 0xff` is the most elegant way to to this conversion. [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) for example complains about using a magic number at this place and it's not a good idea to ignore this value for this check because in other places 255 may really be a magic number which should be avoided. And it's quite annoying to define a constant for stuff like this on my own. So I wonder if there is a standard method in JRE which does this conversion instead? Or maybe an already defined constant with the highest unsigned byte value (similar to Byte.MAX_VALUE which is the highest signed value)

So to keep the question short: How can I convert a byte to an int without using a magic number?

Ok, so far the following possibilities were mentioned:

- Keep using `& 0xff` and ignore the magic number 255 in checkstyle. Disadvantage: Other places which may use this number in some other scope (not bit operations) are not checked then, too. Advantage: Short and easy to read.
- Define my own constant for it and then use code like `& SomeConsts.MAX_UNSIGNED_BYTE_VALUE`. Disadvantage: If I need it in different classes then I have to define my own constant class just for this darn constant. Advantage: No magic numbers here.
- Do some clever math like `b & ((1 << Byte.SIZE) - 1)`. The compiler output is most likely the same because it gets optimized to a constant value. Disadvantage: Pretty much code, difficult to read. Advantage: As long as `1` is not defined as magic number (checkstyle ignores it by default) we have no magic number here and we don't need to define custom constants. And when bytes are redefined to be 16 bit some day (Just kidding) then it still works because then Byte.SIZE will be 16 and not 8.

Are there more ideas? Maybe some other clever bit-wise operation which is shorter then the one above and only uses numbers like 0 and 1?

Comment: I’m not quite certain what you’re really trying to do here, or rather, why. **WARNING: Do not mix bytes and characters!** A byte can only hold 7-bit ASCII characters *not Java characters!* Unicode characters are 21 bits wide, not merely 7 bits **nor even 15/16 bits,** either. Java internally represents  characters  as variable-width (ie, 1 or 2) UTF-16 code units in most situations (*exception:* java.unit.regex necessarily uses UTF-32 for its patterns). You cannot reasonably mask/save off just the low-order 7 bits from a 21-bit quantity and be left with anything sensible and meaningful.

Comment: @tchrist: I never mentioned characters here. It's just bytes. 8 bit bytes. No more, no less.

Comment: Yah, ok.  But *signed* 8-bit quantities.

Comment: @tchrist: No I'm talking about UNSIGNED bytes. I know that Java bytes are signed (And that's a pretty annoying fact in Java. Too bad the 'unsigned' keyword which was part of the Oak specification was never implemented...) So this topic is about converting an unsigned byte to an int. For signed bytes I don't need any magic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This **is** the standard way to do that transformation. If you want to get rid of the checkstyle complaints, try defining a constant, it could help:

```
 public final static int MASK = 0xff;
```

BTW - keep in mind, that it is still a custom conversion. `byte` is a signed datatype so a `byte` can never hold the value `255`. A byte can store the bit pattern `1111 1111` but this represents the integer value `-1`.

So in fact you're doing bit operations - and bit operations *always* require some magic numbers.

---

BTW-2 : Yes, there is a `Byte.MAX_VALUE` constant but this is - because `byte` is signed -  defined as 2<sup>7</sup>-1 (= 127). So it won't help in your case. You need a byte constant for -1.

Comment: Looks like no more ideas are coming in. So I'm accepting the one with the highest vote. Thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 10):

Ignore checkstyle. `0xFF` is *not* a magic number. If you define a constant for it, the constant *is* a magic constant, which is much less understandable than `0xFF` itself. Every programmer educated in the recent centuries should be more familiar with `0xFF` than with his girlfriend, if any.

should we write code like this?

```
for(int i = Math.ZERO; ... )
```

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 provides [`Byte.toUnsignedInt`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-) and [`Byte.toUnsignedLong`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedLong-byte-) (probably for really big bytes) methods:

```
byte b = (byte)255;
int c = Byte.toUnsignedInt(b); // 255
long asLong = Byte.toUnsignedLong(b); // 255
```

Answer (score 3):

Guava to the rescue.

[com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes.toInt](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html#toInt%28byte%29)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a method for this like

```
public static int unsigned(byte x) {
    return int (x & 0xFF);
}
```

which is overloaded for short and int parameters, too (where int gets extended to long).

Instead of 0xFF you could use Byte.MAX_VALUE+Byte.MAX_VALUE+1 to keep FindBug shut, but I'd consider it to be an obfuscation. And it's too easy to get it wrong (s. previous versions).

Comment: Byte.MAX_VALUE+Byte.MAX_VALUE is 254 and not 255. I could use (Byte.MAX_VALUE << 1) + 1 instead (1 is already defined as NOT magic by checkstyle) but... well... No :-)

Comment: Thx for the correction, actually, a constant like Byte.ALL_ONES would be nice.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: Doesn't work. The magic trick only works when you do the AND operation with the byte and an integer (0x000000ff). So when you do the AND operation with two bytes then the result is still a byte which is then converted to an int and that's the point where the 0xff is converted to 0xffffffff (-1).